# Excel, multiple cells, one value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I had no idea where to start in Googling... I have a workbook and want to have 2 cells on different sheets where if one is updated, so is the other. However I want to be able to change *either* cell and the other to update... Is this possible?

Comment: if you give more detail on what is in each cell and what relations do they have maybe somebody could come up with something nonVBA.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a macro fired by the Worksheet Changed event which monitors for changes in either of those cells and copies the change to the other cell.

[MSDN Docs on Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220862%28office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Avoiding macros may be difficult at best here...  You cannot use a formula, because it will be overwritten when you change the values.

Comment: Agreed - can't see how this is possible without a macro unfortunately.  You could have the value in one (other) cell - and then link to it in the two cells - but I'm sure you've thought of that!

Answer (score 3):

Open up your VB editor in Excel and use something like the following in each of the sheets that are affected as well as changing the sheet names and range desired.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(target.Address).Value = target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

As stated in a comment on James' answer, this is not really possible without this minute amount of code unless you are using two additional cells.