# How to synchronize multiple Excel input cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010, circular-dependency, vba

This question was [asked and answered back in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4146716/1982048) but when I follow the directions of the venerable Mr. Buggabill and then run the macro (by editing the target cell) Excel promptly crashes. The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(target.Address).Value = target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I created one version of the macro under Sheet1 (which pushes the target value to A1 on Sheet2) and another version of the macro under Sheet2 (which does the reverse). With only one macro in place this works fine but my intent is to be able to enter a value on either sheet and have the new value propagated into both input cells. Excel crashes because it's a circular reference, right? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that it's not a circular reference, but rather a stack overflow ;)

You might consider turning off eventing inside the execution of your macros.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
...
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This way, the other event handler won't get called when you're poking values onto the other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in another if inside the first one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(target.Address).Value <> target.Value
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(target.Address).Value = target.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

That should stop it from trying to execute when the two values already match. It checks to see if they are the same before doing the update.

Comment: I'm sure this works too but I went with the other answer. Is there any reason why this method might be better/easier/more robust/more scale-able/faster than the other one?

Comment: Why would you change a global setting rather than fix the fundamental logic problem in your code? Your code was doing exactly what you asked it to. Now it will ignore what you ask it to do. That sounds like a bad way to go to me.

Comment: Buttle, thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure ('cause I'm a noob) what is wrong with changing (and then changing back) a global setting though. FWIW, I'm using this code to link dozens of cells together across several sheets. Using Erik Eidt's method adds two lines to each Sub and is easy to implement. Using your method would grow the size of the code by about 50%, making it easier for me to make mistakes. Are there downsides to the other method that I'm not seeing? So far it works fine but I want to write clean code that doesn't introduce new problems so your expertise is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should ask Erik about that. I don't do a lot of coding in Excel anymore. He probably does more. To me, your code is just wrong. And he has given you a way to have it stay wrong and trick it into working. Perhaps that won't give you any problems down the road, but in my experience that kind of shortcut will only lead to future pitfalls. But perhaps I am wrong on this one.

Comment: I know this is old but wanted to add a thought explaining why Erik's answer is not conceptually bad or a risky shortcut. The intent of the Worksheet change handler is to do work in response to user input, not in response to changes made by other code. Using the global Application property is a perfectly simple and appropriate way to prevent undesired triggering of the change handler. Not only is it less code to write, but it results in less code processed when there's a change.

Comment: One thing to be careful for, however, is that an error encountered before re-enabling events could leave the workbook in a broken state. Probably not a problem as long as the action, in this case setting a simple cell text value, is unlikely to fail.